# How to override dependency APIRouter level in pytest?

Tags: python-3.x, pytest, fastapi

I am writing test cases for FAST API endpoints.

One of my module file cud.py

```
from fastapi import APIRouter
from auth.jwt_bearer_default  import JWTBearerDefault

router = APIRouter(
   prefix="",
   dependencies=[Depends(JWTBearerDefault())]
)

@router.post('/endpoint')
def some_function(dataSourceCode: str):
   return dataSourceCode
```

I need to override dependencies of this router so that no need jwt authentication for testing.

Anyone can help me on this?

Comment: Related answer can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77797984/17865804)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here is that `dependency_overrides` maps the actual object passed to `Depends`, but since you're constructing `JWTBearerDefault()` inside `Depends`, you don’t have a reference to the actual object. One possible solution would be to instantiate `JWTBearerDefault` globally and assign it to a variable:

```py
from fastapi import APIRouter
from auth.jwt_bearer_default  import JWTBearerDefault

jwt_bearer = JWTBearerDefault()
router = APIRouter(
   prefix="",
   dependencies=[Depends(jwt_bearer)]
)

@router.post('/endpoint')
def some_function(dataSourceCode: str):
   return dataSourceCode
```

Then, you can use that in your test override:

```py
from router_file import jwt_bearer

app.dependency_overrides[jwt_bearer] = whatever_mock_you_want
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you can only override dependency for all routes of this app (you can not override dependency only for one particular APIRouter).

To override dependency for entire app use this code:

```
app.dependency_overrides[auth.JWTBearerDefault] = JWTBearerDefault_mock
```

After test you can reset this:

```
app.dependency_overrides.pop(auth.JWTBearerDefault)
```

https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/testing-dependencies/

Comment: I already tried your solution but not working at all. If possible, can u give me body of ```JWTBearerDefault_mock```

Comment: I need to see your realization of `auth.JWTBearerDefault` to do that

Comment: Generally, JWTBearerDefault_mock has to just not to raise any exceptions. It's possible that you will have to override subdependencies (if JWTBearerDefault has dependencies that raise exceptions)