# Overriding a route dependency in FastAPI

Tags: python, testing, dependencies, overriding, fastapi

I am using FastAPI

I have a route:

```
@router.post("/product", tags=["product"])
async def create_product(request: Request,
                         id_generator: IdGenerator = Depends(get_id_generator)):
```

I have a dependencies file.

```
def get_id_generator() -> IdGenerator:
    return UUIDIdGenerator()
```

I also have `SomeOtherIdGenerator` I want to use for testing. I just can't get it right.

```
@pytest.fixture
def test_id_generator():
    return SomeOtherIdGenerator()

@pytest.mark.asyncio
async def test_create_product(test_id_generator):
    data = '{ "a": "b" }'
    app.dependency_overrides['get_id_generator'] = lambda : test_id_generator

    client = TestClient(app)
    response = client.post("/product", json={'stuff': data})
    assert response.status_code == 201
    response_data = response.json()
    assert response_data['id'] == "some known value"
```

The result is that I'm still getting a UUID

```
Expected :'some known value'
Actual   :'06864d25-f88c-4382-9d1a-08c8e6951885'
```

I tested with and without the `lambda`

**Solution**

```
 app.dependency_overrides[get_id_generator] = test_id_generator
```

not

```
 app.dependency_overrides['get_id_generator'] = test_id_generator
```

or

```
 app.dependency_overrides['get_id_generator'] = lambda : test_id_generator
```

Comment: `app.dependency_overrides['get_id_generator']` should be `app.dependency_overrides[get_id_generator]` - you need to use the actual function as the key, not the name. There is also no need to define it as a fixture, as it isn't being used as a fixture in pytest, just do `app.dependency_overrides[get_id_generator] = test_id_generator` without the decorator on `test_id_generator`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you are using the `app.dependency_overrides` attribute in your example (i.e., `app.dependency_overrides['get_id_generator'] = lambda : test_id_generator`) is **wrong**, as you are passing a `str` instead of a **function** as the key for the original dependency, as well as passing a `lambda` function instead of just another function as the value for your dependency override.

As per [FastAPI's documentation](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/testing-dependencies/#use-the-appdependency_overrides-attribute)

> #### Use the `app.dependency_overrides` attribute
>
> For these cases, your FastAPI application has an attribute
> `app.dependency_overrides`, it is a simple `dict`.
>
> To override a dependency for testing, you put as a key the original
> dependency (**a function**), and as the value, your dependency
> override (**another function**)
>
> And then FastAPI will call that override instead of the original
> dependency.

### Working Example

```py
from typing import Annotated
from fastapi import Depends, FastAPI
from fastapi.testclient import TestClient

app = FastAPI()


async def common_parameters(q: str | None = None, skip: int = 0, limit: int = 100):
    return {"q": q, "skip": skip, "limit": limit}


@app.get("/items")
async def read_items(commons: Annotated[dict, Depends(common_parameters)]):
    return {"message": "Hello Items!", "params": commons}


client = TestClient(app)


async def override_dependency(q: str | None = None):
    return {"q": q, "skip": 5, "limit": 10}


app.dependency_overrides[common_parameters] = override_dependency


def test_override_in_items():
    response = client.get("/items")
    assert response.status_code == 200
    assert response.json() == {
        "message": "Hello Items!",
        "params": {"q": None, "skip": 5, "limit": 10},
    }
```